# What is the name of sandipani muni's wife?

Tags: rishi

What is the name of sandipani muni's wife ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Sri Radha Krishna Ganodesha Dipika (A lamp to see the associates of Sri Sri Radha-Krsna)](http://www.vrindavan.de/KRISHNA-GANODDESA-DIPIKA.htm) by [Srila Rupa Goswami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rupa_Goswami), the name of Sandipani Muni's wife is **Sumukhi** devi.

The following lines mention it

> Madhumangala has a slightly dark complexion. He wears yellow garments
>   and a garlands of forest flowers. **His father is the saintly Sandipani
>   Muni, his mother the chaste Sumukhi devi**, his sister is
>   Nandimukhi-devi and his parental grandmother is Paurnamasi-devi. 
>    [63-64]
>
> Nandimukhi-devi has a fair complexion and wears exquisite garments.
>   **Her father is Sandipani Muni and her mother is the chaste
>   Sumukhi-devi**. Her brother is Madhumangala and her paternal grandmother
>   is Paurnamasi-devi. She wears various jeweled ornaments and she glows
>   with youthful luster. [98-99]